# Runing a java program, Oracle JDK installed

Tags: java, jdk, compiler

I recently install Oracle JDK, set Environment variables. Everything works fine.

`java -version` on terminal

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have a simple `Hello.java` program I will like to run on terminal.

```
package com.company;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello, world");
    }
}
```

I compile I get my `Hello.class` file generated, in the `.../out/.../com/company/..`

Runs fine in my IDE but I will Eventually have to run form terminal. cd-ed to Hello.class directory.

```
java Hello
```

gives the following error massage.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
```

How can I get it to run from terminal.

Comment: Can you add the content of your simple Hello.java code that you compiled to your question?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032623/368328 for an answer. You need to use the -d flag to create the correct directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the following into a script called Hello.java:

```
package com.company;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello, world");
    }
}
```

The `-d` option in the following command creates the appropriate directory hierarchy. Compile your Java program with: `javac -d . Hello.java` then run it with:

```
java com.company.Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

**The problem generating the error**

Java looks for your application in the path specified by your `package` directive.  In this case `com.company`.

You can compile that simple program by commenting out the package directive, compile it without the package, or create the path and call it by the full path.

```
$ mkdir -p com/company
$ mv Hello.class com/company/
$ java com/company/hello
hello, world
```

If you remove the line `package com.company;` by commenting it out it will work as you have already tried and expect.

If you have a large project with multiple folders for your class files you can use a jar manager program or the command line version **jar** to create a **Hello.jar** file.

Your **IDE** is providing the path and other details specified above.  You can manually create this environment for running your commands (as well as having multiple classes and packages in your archive) using the **jar** command.

### Using the Jar command to create jar programs

You can create your Hello application to run as intended and have the type of path included using this method:

Create the path

```
$ mkdir -p com/company
```

Place your class files in the path of the package line:

```
$ mv Hello.class com/company
```

Create a manifest file to indicate the `main class` location

manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Hello
```

Run the **jar** command to create the package

$    jar cfm test.jar manifest.txt com/

You will now have a new file created, called **test.jar**.  The second argument could have been named anything including **Hello.jar** or just **hello**.  The new file can be run in a number of ways:

```
$ java -jar test.jar
$ ./test.jar
```

If you have created the jar file by with the second argument being `hello`, you could run it with:

```
$ ./hello
```

You could also rename a **java.jar** file to any name after it's created and run it by that name.

Running a Java class is very restrictive in that it has to be run by the class name by which it was compiled.

To run a jar file as a command without the "-jar" argument you would have to change the permission bit (`chmod +x Hello.jar`).

**Jar Command Details**

The jar arguments in this example are:

```
    -c  Create a new archive
    -f  Specify the archive (jar filename)
    -m  Include manifest information from the specified manifest file
```

Jar is installed along as part of the JDK package.  You can get more details of using from the man pages (`man jar`) as well as a quick help by running it without an argument.